# jQuery UI monthpicker should close when month is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datepicker

I have this monthpicker based on datepicker plugin: `http://jsfiddle .net/ um65otbn/`

On the original datepicker, when a day is clicked, the picker closes and date is pasted on the input.

On this monthpicker, with the calendar grid hidden, when month is selected the picker doesn't close. User must still click Done.

Where is the event that closes the picker and pastes on the input, and how to hook it into the month and year selects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement the functionality you described use the [`onChangeMonthYear`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onChangeMonthYear) event.

```
onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, opts){
    $(".monthpicker").datepicker( "setDate", new Date(year, month - 1, 1) );
    $(".monthpicker").datepicker("hide");
},
```

I've updated your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6zckwsn5/